# Como poner un botón en un tableadapter en C#

Tags: c#

necesito de su apoyo, lo que pasa es que quiero crear un table adapter donde incluya en cada fila un boton.
Ejemplo:
Tengo una tabla llamada libros y en esta tabla tengo el nombre y la ruta del libro:

| Nombre   | Ruta        |

Hago un table adapter donde acceso a estos dos campos, sin embargo en lugar de mostrar la ruta quiero mostrar un boton o link que me permita descargar el libro.
PD. Estoy usando VS 2013 y Dev Express

Comment: Bienvenido..Eduardo..., te saludamos y te damos la bienvenida al sitio!, te invito a realizar el [tour] para 
conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio y obtener tu primera 
[medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Con respecto a la realización de preguntas que estas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas excelentes respuestas, **es muy importante leer [ask]**,  te sugiero modificar tu pregunta, agregar lo que has realizado, más información, etc, saludos!

Comment: el tableadapter no lleva botones. .en tal caso el boton va en la vista, y para eso necesitamos ver la vista.. y si usas dev express es muy probable que te deje poner el boton sin mas problema...